# Why C++ not have in starting double main() or like that and only int/void main()?

Tags: c++, primes

Also how would I write a program to work on a very large number. I want to find the largest prime factor of a number in the range of 600000000000

Comment: Those are two really unrelated questions.

Comment: And the second one is not really a question.

Comment: Why would you need to return a double from main? The main function returns an int to the operating system to indicate success or failure. It cannot return void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that int main () returns an exit code of the program. If returned 0 - everything is fine. You need to perform calculations in this function because it is the program entry point. If the number is too large advise to use the example of long arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

int main => return 0; which indicates if the program finished it's running as the programmer expected. Return 2^31 gives one enough numbers for indicating error codes.

For large numbers linked lists can be used.